# Is fixing this water pipe doable on my own

Tags: plumbing, water

I have these water pipes (for hot and cold water) exposed for easy access.
There is this tee joint which has been corroding for the past few years.
I would like to replace it, but before I call a professional I'd like to assess if this is something I could do myself with the right tools. The problem is I do not have experience with this kind water pipe work, and it is hard to play with the parts and threads with all the piping in active use.

Prior assessments of contractors whom I called for a quote included, among others, suggestion that because of rigidity of the connections the tee joint has to be sawn off.

The water flows from the right. There are two valves to shut off both cold and hot water. In the middle is a mixer, which takes some of the cold water flow. The tee joint is right above it. Pipes on the left lead to final outlets in the apartment.

So the main question is as already stated, is this something I could fix myself?
If the answer is yes, what kind of tools would I need? What connections would I need to unscrew and in which order, and in which direction? What addidional replacement parts would I need for this (I have two already purchased)? Would I need to hammer the wall around some of the pipes?[image: overall view]

I suspect some of the existing connections have length which can be adjusted - please correct me if I am wrong.
[image: close up][image: replacement parts][image: top view]

**[EDIT]** Extra pictures requested in the comments: [image: top view of hot water meter][image: face of the mixer's knob][image: side closeup of the mixer]

**[EDIT 2]** As a final comment - thank you for all the contributions and suggestions. I would like to add another idea I had (pic attached) that could help alleviate some of the alignment headaches, but I might be jumping the shark with it. [image]

Comment: Does the water come in at the right on top, or the right on the bottom, or both?

Comment: Both. cold water comes from top right, hot from bottom right.

Comment: I would love it if you would explain more.  You have unmetered cold water, metered hot water, and you mix them before feeding your fixtures where I assume you feed both the cold and the mixed water and can mix them some more?   I have never seen that.  What country are you in?  What is the source of the hot and cold water?  Are they completely independent?

Comment: The "mixer" is the white, knob looking thing on the lower T? It can be set to guarantee 100% that no water will escape upwards from the Hot water supply side? i.e. it can be used as a shutoff valve? Can you get us a close up of the _end_ of that mixing valve (showing any labeling that may be there), as well as a close up of the face of the other round device on the lower supply line (which looks a lot like a small meter)?

Comment: @jay613 The meter for cold water is in the shaft outside the apartment. Fixtures receive either cold water (does not go through the mixer, it leaves through the top left splitter) of mixed cold & hot water (it leaves through the bottom left splitter). Extra mixing is done in the taps. This is in Europe, Poland specifically.

Comment: @FreeMan That is correct. The white knob controls how much cold water you want to mix into hot water feed. Unless I am terribly wrong I should be able to separate flow of cold water completely. I will add more pictures.

Comment: Is the mixer thermostatic?  Perhaps a safety feature required by law if you have hot water supplied from outside your home?

Comment: New problem: Now I understand what's going on .... the rusty T is directly connected to the main cold water shutoff.  That's another source of stress.  Is there another shutoff outside (at the meter?) in case you cannot separate the tee from the inside shutoff?

Comment: @jay613 If I remember that correctly, there is also additional cold water shutoff in the shaft outside of the apartment.

Comment: @jay613 Is the mixer thermostatic? Unfortunately, I don't know.

Comment: @FreeMan I've edited the post with three additional pictures. The mixer has only four markings I can identify: "3/4" next to the know, "-" on the top end, "+" on the bottom end, and "M" on the left side end. The round device with red-colored elements is a hot water meter.

Comment: If you turn the white knob all the way to "+", turn off the hot water supply valve, and turn on a hot faucet in the bathroom, does cold water come out?   (I might have this backwards, maybe it's all the way to "-" but I think "+" means "more hot")

Comment: I'd do an experiment. Turn the mixer knob all the way to the `-` direction. Turn a hot water tap on somewhere in the house and hold a thermometer in the water stream. Wait for the temp to stabilize and make note of it. Next, turn the cold water shutoff to the off position. Repeat the temp test at the _same_ tap. If the two temps are the same, then it would appear that the mixer _can_ fully shut off the cold water. If they're different (and the cold water tap off is hotter), then the mixer will _not_ shut off the cold 100%. If the cold water valve value is hotter, you've done it wrong do over.

Comment: heh, @jay613 and I posted at nearly the same time. My assumption was that `-` was the _minimum_ setting for cold water mixing into the hot water stream, but I may have assumed incorrectly. If the test above gives wildly different readings, go all the way to the `+` direction and try again. Also, before you start the test, make a mark on the knob and somewhere on the valve base so you can easily return to _very close_ to the current setting.

Comment: FreeMan the more I think about this the more I wonder why either of us thought we know what + or - meant :).      Wojciech I added high level instructions to my answer.

Comment: I would also suggest taking a wire wheel and cleaning up all the corrosion/mineral build up on the outside of all the pipes & fittings. Use a wire brush where you can't get the wheel in. Since this is exposed, that'll make it look nicer, plus, you'll get a better view of exactly what's going on, and it'll make it more obvious more quickly if you've got a leak in the future since you'll see it building up again on nice, clean pipes instead of having to detect additional build up on already messy pipes.

Comment: I tried to adjust the mixer but the knob wont move. So I did another simpler experiment, which answers how does the mixer work: I shut down cold water and opened one of the taps. The result was no cold water running. This means that flow of cold water to the mixer is unidirectional.

Comment: I accepted @jay613's answer but FreeMan's comments were also informative and added a lot to the discussion.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129067/discussion-on-question-by-wojciech-migda-is-fixing-this-water-pipe-doable-on-my).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hire a plumber!

This is an easy DIY project for someone with some experience, but by the sound of it not something you should attempt yourself.   If you are at the level of experience where you do not know what tools or replacement parts you need, you should hire a professional to do this.

The reason is that with the water shut off, if you discover you are missing a part or if you break something and need to go replace it,  your home will be entirely without water until you do.   No water do drink, no toilets.  You can take steps like filling pots with water and "not flushing" but that only goes so far.  How long can your family survive without water?  12 hours?  24?  Three days until you learn to fix this and finally get all the right parts?

My approach to DIY is always: Is it possible I will make my home uninhabitable?  Will my family need to move to a hotel?   If the answer is yes, I hire a professional.  You should do that.     (The other criteria is "will I probably hurt myself"?  But that's not a big factor here).

**[ EDIT given new info about independent supplies ]**

If you have two ***independent*** sources of water and you live by yourself you are in a much better position to attempt this repair.  From comments, you have separate cold and hot water supplies and mixer for the hot.    If you run into big trouble with the T, you have several options to partially restore water service.  Perhaps the mixer can be adjusted just by turning something to shut off the cold side.  Perhaps you can disconnect the cold supply to the mixer and just put a cap on there.  Perhaps you can remove the mixer and temporarily replace it with a flexible hose connecting the hot supply to the hot manifold.   You have a lot of options so you will probably not be stuck entirely without water for days.

##### Here is a guide to how you should approach this if you choose to try:

With two water supplies you are in better shape to attempt this but the rusty damaged part is connected directly to your cold shutoff valve so if there is not an additional outside shutoff you need to proceed carefully.

1. Turn off both supplies and also the cold supply outside if there is one.
2. Disconnect the four cold hoses from the manifold.
3. Disconnect the mixer from the cold or, if it won’t turn due to corrosion, saw the pipe feeding cold to the mixer and then disconnect the stub from the mixer.
4. If possible turn the mixer to “only hot” or if not, place a cap on the cold supply side.  Turn the hot water back on and check for leaks, then turn it off. You will only use this "hot water only" configuration if you encounter big problems.
5. With the cold manifold still connected, remove the tee from the cold supply.  This is the most precarious step in the process.  We keep the manifold connected because it might provide some leverage to turn the tee from the supply valve.     If there is no outside shutoff, and you feel like you might damage the cold supply valve, STOP and call a plumber.
6. Try to remove the tee from the cold manifold.  If you cannot, buy a new manifold.
7. Install the new tee.  Connect it to the cold supply and to the mixer.   Screw a cap into the cold output of the tee and temporarily turn the cold water back on to look for leaks in your installation so far.  Then turn it back off and remove the cap.
8. Replace the cold manifold and replace the distribution hoses.  Turn the cold water on and check for leaks.
9. Turn the hot water back on, restore the mixer to the desired setting, check for leaks and check the temperature at the taps.

##### To answer some of your specific questions:

**Tools:** Two large pipe wrenches for removing and replacing the main fittings and one small pipe wrench or  open wrench small enough to fit and remove the four cold hoses.  Small hacksaw.

**Supplies:**

- Thread tape.
- If the cold hoses use compression washers (I don’t know), new compression washers.
- Shutoff caps that will fit the cold output of the tee and the cold input of the mixer.
- New tee.
- New bit of pipe to connect the tee to the mixer.
- Not clear how the tee is connected to the mixer, I think it might use compression couplings, so you'll need a couple of those.

Should you hammer the wall?  — No.  Maybe I don’t understand this question.

Which way to turn?  Practice with those new parts you bought.  Everything is the same but it's possible you have some threaded and some compression couplings.  I can't tell.

Your biggest problem will be that trying to remove a rusty threaded part without breaking the good parts requires experience to know how hard you can turn and when to stop trying and saw it off instead.

Comment: Unless I remove the mixer I can switch it not to take in any cold water - this would still give me hot water supply. Not an ideal situation, but since I live by myself I could survive that for a couple of days.

Comment: Having gone down the "oh, this will be simple, I've done this kind of work before" route, then ended up with 3 runs to the store (and I'm 20+ minutes from the closest hardware store) to get the right parts, an hour at the store trying to sort out exactly what part it is that I need _this_ time (and a trip to the bathroom while I'm there because there's no water at home), I have to endorse this answer as opposed to the DIY route which I'd normally encourage.

Comment: If you live by yourself, fill a few bottles/pots with water to drink and cook, if you have a neighbor who will let you use their toilet and maybe  you can go to a gym or public shower if you have to ... yes this could be a great educational rewarding DIY experience.  Covid lockdowns might make neighbors and public bathrooms harder to access than before.

Comment: @jay613 in your view, can this be done with the mixer still in place, limiting the effort to the tee and its closest vicinity?

Comment: Note that the update is full of "may" and "perhaps" - there's no guarantee!

Comment: Ya I'm getting nervous about this ... realizing the rusty part is connected to what may be the main shutoff .. if there's no outside shutoff this is definitely not DIY!

Comment: Wow, hey, nice lateral thinking there. Removing all the PEX from the mainifold to make room to maneuver things is a _great_ idea! _Adds that to mental checklist of options for future projects._

Comment: @FreeMan tx but I don't see any option!   Looks like threaded on the left and right sides of the tee so MUST remove pex to turn anything.  I'm stumped about something .. looks like a compression nut on the cold inlet to the mixer, but what was the connector on the south side of the tee?  It does not look like compression, but if not ... what?   If it was threaded did the plumber make a piece of pipe threaded at one end?  Or did the tee include a little tail on that side?  I can't tell.

Comment: step 7 is impossible as as this stage neither the tee ot the mixer can be moved, so there's no way to install the pipe.

Comment: I can't imagine that T coming off other than by cutting.  It appears to be galvanized and not isolated from the copper.  With that big a booboo expect other problems also.  I would also get replacements for every part connected to that T on the assumption I wouldn't be able to reuse them.

Comment: Hire a plumber. This *isn't* an easy project even for someone with experience. This is one and a half pots of coffee, five trips to the store, and two days without water, because this is iron pipe, galvanized, copper, brass, and stainless, all of which have to go until it's all brass or copper, or using dielectrics between anything that's not those or plastic. - I wouldn't touch this w/o *two* of *everything* in that picture on hand.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have chosen a brass tee to replace the rusting galvanized tee, and a reducer to reduce the branch size down to half inch. This is the right thing to do.

But you don't have all the parts you will need.

Expect to need to replace the ferrule on that short copper pipe and the nipple and nut at the top end may need replacing too (especially if they are not brass).

To access the rusted tee, you'll need to disconnect all those plastic lines and then unscrew the manifold towards the corner of the room.

To get that copper pipe out of the tee you'll have to undo the union on the outlet of the temperature valve, the nut at the top of the copper pipe, and the union on the left of the water meter. If the ferrule or the nut at the top of the copper is damaged you may need to replace the whole copper pipe and both ferrules.

For reassembly you'll need hemp fiber or Teflon tape to seal the threaded joins to the tee.

So in addition to the parts you have, you should also get a replacement copper pipe and ferrule for both ends and all the hardware needed to connect the top end of the copper pipe to the tee, plus the Teflon tape to seal the threaded joints.

Answer (score 2):

Can you do it yourself, yes.

Are you allowed to do it yourself, maybe,  apartments might need professional, depending on your local laws/regulations.

Tools required probably a couple decent adjustable wrenches, a couple pipe wrenches, a hack saw and wire brush, and pipe sealing tape/paste.

Pieces required are all the ones that don't come apart nicely.  Quite a few five minute jobs take 5 hours of running around town for extra pieces.

Some screw in pieces sometimes are very hard to unscrew, pieces around the tee, probably the worst.

Comment: I own the apartment so I am allowed to do quite wide range of modifications.

Comment: When it comes to fitting all the pieces together, is my assumptions that some of the connections have adjustable length (like the one between the tee and the mixer) correct? I suspect that not having such option makes this many times harder.

Comment: They are not really adjustable, except for a tiny amount.  The rest of the pipes should be kept in a straight line, because if off centre, leaks are easier to have.  If need to adjust one, then need to adjust others as well.

Comment: @WojciechMigda there is little to no adjustability in any of these lines. They're all hard copper or steel (looks like you've got a good mix), and they won't bend. You _may_ get some flexibility because of the PEX pipe on the left of the image, but in my view, it could still be difficult to get all the pieces to line up.

Comment: @FreeMan That sounds like a solid argument against me undertaking this. Aligning everything correctly does no look trivial; the replacement tee I have differs in some length dimensions compared to the rusty one, which I hoped to be able to compensate using some adjustable parts.

Comment: @WojciechMigda the adjustment you do have is in the _length_ of the pipe you cut to go between the two Ts. However, if the new T is longer than the old one, that will offset its outlet side which means it will no longer line up with the input of the T below it. You have zero room to adjust that because they're connected to hard lines where they penetrate the wall. You can move the left side a bit to get the new T and the new section of vertical pipe in, but everything _must_ line up the same when you're done or it will leak.

Comment: You _might_ be able to get a bit of PEX in for the vertical run between the two Ts, and that _might_ give you enough room to make the adjustment you need, but that means getting your hands on short bits of PEX (you don't need a big length and probably don't want loads of extra sitting around) and PEX crimping tools. If you can rent them, no big deal, if you have to buy, that's expensive for 2 crimps. Also, that means a different new T and replacing whatever's on top of the mixer with PEX compatible fittings.